# Windows Firewall doesn't allow an app to spin up a server

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, grpc, windows-firewall

I have a .net core app that when runs, spins up a grpc server to listen for inbound  network connections. Firewall allows .netcore app to run and listen for connections, but it doesn't allow grpc server to bind to any port. Even though I added a rule for the port in question to allow connections, I still can't get it to work. For other applications, firewall prompts me if I want to allow access to certain app, but for this case I don't get any prompt. How can I allow access to server that runs a server?

Comment: To clarify, this is a program that runs from your user session and not as a headless Windows Service?

Comment: @Dai From Visual Studio, I run my code. It's an asp.netcore app. In start up of the app, it initializes a grpc server. At that point grpc server fails to bind to port.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted 2 days on this and finally got the answer. Windows update caused certain valid to use ports to be excluded and as a result I couldn't run any app that listens on those excluded ports.

Here is a link to Microsoft article.
[Windows Update blocking ports](https://web.archive.org/web/20190407185556/https://support.microsoft.com/ha-latn-ng/help/4093046/ports-blocked-after-you-install-monthly-rollup-package-kb4074588)